# NuxtJS: nuxt-links working in yarn dev but not production (Netlify)

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, netlify, nuxtjs3

I am dealing with a particular issue where the Nuxt Links in my vuetify navigation drawer seems to work intermittently

```
<v-navigation-drawer
        color="#fdfcfc"
        width="250"
        mini-variant-width="70px"
        expand-on-hover
        rail
        mini-variant
        app
      >
        <v-list-item>
          <v-btn icon> <v-img src="/puffinS.png"/> </v-btn>
        </v-list-item>
  
        <v-list>
          <NuxtLink v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" :to="item.to" exact>
            <v-list-item>
              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon color="#000000">{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-action>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title><v-btn
                  size="small"
                  class="ma-2"
                  color="#D8FBFD"
                >{{ item.title }}</v-btn></v-list-item-title>
                
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
          </NuxtLink>
        </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
```

Page in question linked [here](https://www.sharif-sircar.com/) where when clicked on the URL would change to correct directory but the page doesn't change, if I was to reload the page now on the correct directory, it would work, to further add to the symtoms, once it starts working, it keeps working. This same nuxtlinks work straight off the bat when using it on my local host with yarn dev.

At the moment it's running on netlify using yarn generate command.

Any help would be appreciated!

Trying to collect some rep points, wanted to start somewhere, perfect opportunity to make my first post here!

Answer (score 0):

Since the time this was posted, after some digging I found out an old left over code for my old form implementation was causing that to happen, removing the components I was using anymore solved it and the other thing that also solved it was disabling SSR in nuxt.config.js (Re: [post here](https://answers.netlify.com/t/nuxt-links-working-in-localhost-but-not-production/89831/5) for info on this bit)

Thank you!